# Is there a way to create nodes from cloud formation that can ssh to each other without passwords?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am creating up an AWS Cloud formation template which sets up a set of nodes which must allow keyless ssh login amongst themselves. i.e. One controller must be able to login to all slaves with its private key. The controllers private key is generated dynamically so I do not have access to be able to hard code it into the User-Data of the Template or pass it as a parameter to the template.

Is there a way in Cloud Formation templates to add the controller's public key to slave nodes' authorized keys files?

Is there some other way to use security groups or IAMS to do what is required?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pas the Public key o the master server to the slave nodes in the form of `user-data`. Cloudformation does support user-data. You may have to figure out the syntax for the same.

In other words, consider it as a simple bash script which will copy the master servers's public key to the slaves. and then you pass this bash script as suer-data so that it gets executed for the 1st time the instance is created.

You will find tons of goggle searches on above information.

Comment: I know about the user data but since the key pair is generated on the controller after it boots up it cannot be hard-coded into the user data.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem with IAM machine roles. You can grant specific machines certain AWS rights. IAM roles do not apply to ssh access, but to AWS api calls, like s3 bucket access or creating ec2 instances.

Therefore, a solution might look like:

1. Create a controller machine role which can write to a particular S3 bucket.
2. Create a slave machine role which can read from that bucket.
3. Have the controller create an upload a public key into the bucket.
4. Since you don't know if the controller is created before the slaves, you'll have to have cloud-init set up a cron job every couple minutes that downloads the key from the bucket if it hasn't done so yet.